# Не удаётся вызвать статический метод класса. PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

Доброго времени суток! Проблема заключается в следующем: при выполнение actionа в контроллере не удается вызвать метод из модели. Вызов выглядит следующим образом:

```
$userId = User::checkUserData($email, $password);
```

Код самого actionа:

```
public function actionLogin() {

    $email = '';
    $password = '';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $errors = false;

        $userId = User::checkUserData($email, $password);

        if ($userId == false) {
            $errors[] = "Неверные E-mail или пароль.";
        }
        else {
            User::auth($userId);

            header("Location: /cabinet/");
        }
    }

    require_once ROOT.'/views/user/login.php';

    return true;

}
```

Код метода модели:

```
public static function checkUserData($email, $password) {

    $db = Db::getConnection();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email AND password = :password";

    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->execute();

    $user = $result->fetch();
    if ($user) {
        return $user['id'];
    }

    return false;

}
```

В логах нашел такую ошибку: PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

```
$result = call_user_func_array(array($controllerObject, $actionName), $parameters);
```

Все переменные не являются пустыми.

Данная проблема наблюдается при вызове любого метода, а не конкретно этого. При чем в Open Server под Windows этот же код выполняется нормально.

ОС - Ubuntu 16.04.1, сервер - LAMP, PHP версии 7.0.

Comment: Так а ошибку какую пишет? Может классы не подгружены(права доступа к файлам)?

Comment: Добавил про ошибку.

Comment: Так оно вам говорит, что callback  не правильный. А что в переменных  `$controllerObject`, `$actionName`?

Comment: В данном случае UserController и actionLogin соответственно.

Comment: Значит не загрузили контроллер.

Comment: как и ожидалось, судя по тексту ошибки, статически метод класса `User` тут не при делах

Comment: В чем может быть проблема из-за которой не загружаются контроллеры?

Comment: Неправильно прописаны пути, неправильно выставленны права на файлы, файлы отсутствуют.